# How to adjust the item in bottom of the screen to top of keyboard when keyboard popup

Tags: kotlin, android-softkeyboard, android-jetpack-compose, keyboard-events

How to adjust the item in the bottom to the keyboard top when keyboard pop-ups?

When the user clicks the `Textfield` the keyboard pop up and it hides the custom button which is at the bottom.
How to adjust the button to the top of the keyboard when the keyboard pop-ups?

```
CommonNormalEditText(
    textValue = name,
    onValueChange = {
        commonViewModel.onLanguageChange(it)
    },
    placeHolderText = stringResource(id = R.string.search_language),
)
Column() {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(5.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .weight(1f)) {
        itemsIndexed(languageFilterList) { index, item ->
            LanguageSingleCard(
                onClick = {
                    selectedPosition = index
                    sharedPrefs.setAppLanguage(LANGUAGE_SELECTION_KEY, item.languageCode)
                    if (selectedPosition != item.selectedId) {
                        selectedPosition = item.selectedId
                    } else {
                        selectedPosition = -1
                    }
                },
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.light_grey),
                languageSelectionModel = item,
                selectedPosition)
        }
    }
    CustomButtonWithLoader(
        buttonText = stringResource(id = R.string.continue_txt),
        textColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
        gradient = gradient,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        onClick = {
            navController.popBackStack()
            navController.navigate(Screen.WalkThroughScreen.route)
        },
    )
}
```

[image]

The Continue button should adjust to the top of the keyboard when it pop-ups.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. It not works. Any other possible solution?

Comment: How exactly it not works? Sure you've added `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`?

Comment: I add the above line in my activity. It does not work. I am struck here.

Comment: You also need `.navigationBarsWithImePadding()`, as I showed in my example. You can try copying full code in your activity to see if it works

Comment: Not working. It Expands my view. I attach the screen shot also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237951/discussion-between-suman-radhakrishnan-and-philip-dukhov).

Comment: I don't know how you've adopted my solution to your code. I can't run your code because of many unknown code. Have you tried running my example?

Comment: I am using column as parent and inside column { Textfield, LazyGrid with weight (1f) and Button } Nothing complicated. But Button not adjust to the textfield keyboard pop up.

Comment: Check this out: https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/